# BeautifoulSoup not returning everything in Facebook

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract all the pages liked by a given person on Facebook. Therefore, I'm using Python with BeautifulSoup and selenium to automatize the connection.

However, even though my code works, it doesn't actually return all the results (on my own profile, for instance, it only returns about 20% of all pages).

I read that it might be the parser used in BeautifulSoup, but I tried a bunch of them (html.parser, lxml...) and it's always the same thing. 
Could that be because Facebook is dynamically generating the pages with AJAX? But then I have Selenium, which should correctly interpret it..!
Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

id_user = ""

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://facebook.com')
driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys('')
driver.find_element_by_id('pass').send_keys('')
driver.find_element_by_id('loginbutton').click()
time.sleep(2)

pages_liked = "https://www.facebook.com/search/" + id_user + "/pages-liked"

driver.get(pages_liked)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

likes_divs = soup.find_all('a', class_="_32mo")

for div in likes_divs:
    print(div['href'].split("/?")[0])
    print(div.find('span').text)
```

Thank you very much,

Loïc

Comment: you can also use official facebook api.

Comment: Yes...Problem being that we do not know what is really returned(integrity, volume limited). The aim is really to get through that using selenium and other means to retrieve what's needed (bs4...)

Comment: did you scroll down?

Comment: @kcorlidy: no I didn't. But I'm starting to think that the problem comes from that (AJAX). I'll retry my code accordingly  (finding a way to scroll the facebook page with selenium ) and will tell you ! txs

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is famous for make web scrapers's life dificult... That said, looks like you do your homework correctly, the snipet looks rigth to the point.

Start to look into 'driver.page_source', what Selenium gets... if the information is in there, the problem is within BeautifulSoup, if its not, Facebook found an strategy to hide the page (looking at browser signature or fingerprint - yes, these are diferent concepts).